# Get the last inserted row's primary key in php

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

i'm working on php and i want insert something in my sql data-base and get the row's inserted primary key in the same time so i've done something like this to insert

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO `saisie` (`sid`, `reference`) VALUES (NULL,?)";
$set = $db->prepare($SQL);
$result = $set->execute(array($refCode));
```

but i don't know what to do to get the ***sid*** of that inserted row

Comment: If your `$db` is a PDO object (or a wrapper around that) it probably has a [lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) function, so try `$id = $db->lastInsertId();`

Comment: i have found this answer few minutes ago and i'm using it, but what if there is two people inserting in the same time? this won't cause a problem ?

Comment: It's connection specific, so no worries.

Comment: I got it, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

you could use this to get the last inserted ID

```
$id = mysqli_insert_id($db); or
$id = $db->mysqli_insert_id(); or
$id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: what if there is two people inserting in the same time? this won't cause a problem ?

Comment: they will surely insert one after the other

Comment: Okay i will accept your answer, but please add 
`$id = $db->lastInsertId();` to the answer because my $db is a PDO object, and thank you for answering